# Scala dynamic instantiation with default arguments

Tags: scala, dynamic, reflection, creation

Is there a way to dynamically instantiate a Scala case class having one or more default parameters specified?

I'm looking for the dynamic (reflection-based) equivalent of this:

```
case class Foo( name:String, age:Int = 21 )
val z = Foo("John")
```

Right now if I try this I get an exception:

```
val const = Class.forName("Foo").getConstructors()(0)
val args = Array("John").asInstanceOf[Array[AnyRef]]
const.newInstance(args:_*)
```

If I add a value for age in my parameter array, no problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Instantiating a case class with default args via reflection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16939511/instantiating-a-case-class-with-default-args-via-reflection)

Comment: exact dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034142/how-do-i-access-default-parameter-values-via-scala-reflection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Argument with default value are a compile-time thing. The compiler will feed in the default value for a call where the parameter is missing. No such thing with reflection, all the less with java reflection, which is not aware at all of default arguments.

Comment: You can get default value in run-time as method.

Comment: How?  I don't (yet) have an instance of that object--I'm in the process of instantiating it.

Comment: @Greg in this case - companion object.

Answer (score 1):

You can get default parameters as methods of object in runtime.

In case of constructor parameters - companion object methods (scala 2.9.3).

```
$ echo 'class Test(t: Int = 666)' > test.scala
$ scalac -Xprint:typer test.scala
...
<synthetic> def init$default$1: Int @scala.annotation.unchecked.uncheckedVariance = 666
```

You can't rely on the name of this method. (scala 2.10.1):

```
scala> Test.$lessinit$greater$default$1
res0: Int = 666
```

I [don't know](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6468) how to get default parameters for constructor, but in case of `case class` you could get `apply` method default parameters. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16942995/406435).

Comment: @som-snytt: the name is different in `2.9.3` and `2.10.1`, so one should not use the name, but generate in using `defaultGetterName`.

Comment: @som-snytt: your comment makes me want to create method `\`<init>\``.