# How a val value bean changed

Tags: mysql, scala, mybatis

I use scala with mybatis:

Space.scala:

```
case class Space(
              val id: Long ,
              spaceName:String)
```

SpaceDao:

```
   val space=Space(0,"space name")
   val mapper = session.getMapper(classOf[SpaceMapper])
   val result = mapper.insertSpace(space)
   println(space.id)
```

The result space id is the auto increment number of mysql, not 0. but both space and space.id is val, why a val value can be changed?

Comment: how can you prove that `space` id has changed?

Comment: I tracked the code when running a inserting, it's same object but the `id` value is change by mybatis in class SetFieldInvoker,   after "field.set(target, args[0])", the field is "private final long model.Space.id"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scala Reflection to update a case class val](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21431263/scala-reflection-to-update-a-case-class-val)

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved via [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/)(which is used by [SetFieldInvoker](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/jacoco/org.apache.ibatis.reflection.invoker/SetFieldInvoker.java.html)):

> Reflection is commonly used by programs which require the ability to
>   examine or modify the runtime behavior of applications running in the
>   Java virtual machine. This is a relatively advanced feature and should
>   be used only by developers who have a strong grasp of the fundamentals
>   of the language. With that caveat in mind, reflection is a powerful
>   technique and can enable applications to perform operations which
>   would otherwise be impossible.

Also see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful).