# Can I invoke case class copy method with dynamic parameter without explicit reflection?

Tags: scala, reflection, case-class

The problem is that I have some independent case classes with different fields.
I wanted to write a method that returns instance of the case class of given type with one of parameters changed.

```
def updateParam[C : ClassTag](c: C, paramName: String, paramValue: Any): C = ...
```

I took advantage of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21578293/8124611), but it involves the use of reflection mechanism which is not so beautiful.
Is there a possibility to avoid using reflection or maybe at least hide it under the hood of some library?

Comment: Is there any good reason to not just use the `copy` method? `c.copy(paramName = paramValue)` does exactly that, but in type safe way, without any `Any`s.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to invoke *same* function on instances of *different classes*, then it is *polymorphism*.

If those classes are unrelated, the polymorphism is *ad-hoc*.

The usual way to implement ad-hoc polymorphism in Scala is by using typeclasses. Here, you can implement the typeclass `Copyable`:

```
trait Copyable[C] {
  def copy(c: C, paramName: String, value: Any): C
}
```

and implement your method as follows:

```
def updateParam[C: Copyable](c: C, paramName: String, paramValue: Any): C = {
  implicitly[Copyable[C]].copy(c, paramName, paramValue)
}
```

Now, if you have two unrelated classes, which somehow ended up unrelated despite the fact that you want to use them in the same context:

```
case class Foo(paramName: String, foo: Int)
case class Bar(paramName: String, bar: Option[Double])
```

you can provide type-classes that make them `Copyable`:

```
implicit object FooIsCopyable extends Copyable[Foo] {
  def copy(f: Foo, paramName: String, value: Any): Foo = {
    if (paramName == "paramName") {
      f.copy(paramName = value.asInstanceOf[String])
    } else if (paramName == "foo") {
      f.copy(foo = value.asInstanceOf[Int])
    } else {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Foo has no param `" + paramName + "`")
    }
  }
}

implicit object BarIsCopyable extends Copyable[Bar] {
  def copy(b: Bar, paramName: String, value: Any): Bar = {
    if (paramName == "paramName") {
      b.copy(paramName = value.asInstanceOf[String])
    } else if (paramName == "bar") {
      b.copy(bar = value.asInstanceOf[Option[Double]])
    } else {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bar has no param `" + paramName + "`")
    }
  }
}
```

and then use your method like this:

```
val f = Foo("hello", 42)
val b = Bar("bye", Some(58.0))

println(updateParam(f, "paramName", "hello, world"))
println(updateParam(b, "paramName", "obey"))
```

which then prints:

```
Foo(hello, world,42)
Bar(obey,Some(58.0))
```

However, while you *can* do this, it's not entirely clear why you would want to. How did it happen that `Foo` and `Bar` end up in the same situation, so that you end up with essentially duck-typing, requiring method `copy`? Maybe you should eliminate the root-cause in the first place.

---

You might also want to take a look at *lenses*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
But it means that for any new case class I'll have to implement implicit object with copy logic. Is there any other option?

Comment: As for the entire situation. I have a method where lambda with some logic passed depending on type (which is presented by case class).
I noticed that all the difference is just in passing parameter to change in object.

`(x, c) => c.copy(paramName = x)`
I wanted to generalize it somehow or even better to get rid of these lambdas passing at all.

Comment: @pavelbel As I briefly mentioned in the end, the `(x, c) => c.copy(paramName = x)` thing looks very much like `(lens[Foo] >> 'paramName).set(c)(x)` (see [here](https://www.scala-exercises.org/shapeless/lenses)). Maybe the thing into which you are passing those lambdas can also be abstracted away by some other "optics". But I'm not sure, I don't know enough about your use case. Maybe you could consider updating your question with more details about the underlying problem, and eventually tag it as `shapeless`, if you deem it useful. Then maybe someone more knowledgeable about lenses could answer